# CSS How to make background image strech like image

Tags: css

Hi everyone I have a problem when setting the background image for div. I want to set a full background image for div. It's almost done but the color is not correct. My picture has the gradient color
My CSS code

```
.cards-section .item-wrapper .item-inner.category_blue {
    background: url('./images/post_blue.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The design 
[image]

My present

[image]

The color is different. Do you know any way to fix it

HTML Code

```
<div class="row cards-wrapper">
   <div class="card col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <div id="post-34" class="card_wrapper post-34 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
         <div class="card_header card_inner fullBackgroundImage category_purple">
            <h5 class="card_header_category">Uncategorized</h5>
            <hr class="card_header_category_break">
            <h3 class="card_title">Post 1</h3>
            <p class="card_modified">Last update: November 21, 2018</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-body  while">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus. In cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Dui nunc mattis enim ut. Semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus. Diam volutpat</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Background Image

[image]

Comment: if you have a colour picker get the color codes and use background:linear-gradient(), instead of background-image.

Comment: Could you provide your html as well? Your css background-image can only cover the size of the div it is the background of, thus can only be as large as the div.

Comment: @Wernerson I have update the html code

Comment: Please post the whole HTML code as I do not see any classed named cards-selection, item-wrapper or any of your other css selectors.

Comment: @Wernerson I have posted the whole HTML. But I don't think it's necessary

Answer (score 1):

If you want your background image to stretch like image, you can use

```
background-size: 100% 100%
```

so no matter the size of container, image will stretch to fill it.

Comment: I don't see any difference. it's same like background size cover

Comment: Well, not really. Cover resizes the background image, but keeps the ratio (so some parts of the image are not visible), while this stretches the background image to fill the container, no matter what the ratio of image/container is, and whole image is visible at all times. You can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Yes, but in this case, the difference between percentage and cover is really low, almost similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because of background-attachment fixed property. The image is resized to fill the whole space, when user will scroll that element. So the image is bigger and you don't see the whole image.

Just try to *remove that fixed property* if you really don't need it there.

Comment: It's not right. Without background-attachment fixed. The background image can't stretch full

Comment: So maybe edit that background image and make it more wider, because browser want to scale proportionally that background.